# How to remove special characters except for characters "ñ / Ñ" and dash "-" in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove special characters in a string but have  "ñ / Ñ" and "-" remain.

So if I have:

`»¿Antonio Ramon-Peñaą`

Result would be:

```
Antonio Ramon-Peña
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PCRE verbs to allow for a set list of characters, if it matches that ignore it. Then for all other characters (because it is not a character you care about) remove them.

```
preg_replace('/[\w\h-](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|./u', '', '»¿Antonio Ramon-Peñaą')
```

For a longer regex explanation see https://regex101.com/r/pCwGuy/1/.  Basically `[\w\h-]` are any horizontal spaces, word characters, or hyphens. The `u` modifier after the closing delimiter expands the `\w` to include word characters outside ascii set. The `.` is any single character.

Alternatively you could match all valid characters then rejoin them.

```
preg_match('/[\w\h-]+/u', '»¿Antonio Ramon-Peñaą', $match);
echo implode('', $match);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This worked. I appreciate the explanation too!